# Sequelize model associations find query using typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript, sequelize.js

where should I define the types of fields which get populated after join operation. I have followed the sequelize documentation but was unable to find a solution

this is my sequelize model definitions

User.ts (User Mode)

```
interface UserAttributes {
    id: number;
    username: string;
    first_name: string;
    last_name: string;
    password: string;
    created_by: number;
    created_on: Date;
    updated_by?: number;
    updated_on?: Date;
}

type UserCreationAttributes = Optional<UserAttributes, 'id' | 'updated_by' | 'updated_on'>;

const User: ModelDefined<UserAttributes, UserCreationAttributes> = sequelize.define(
    'user',
    {
        id: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            autoIncrement: true,
            primaryKey: true
        },
        username: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull: false
        },
        first_name: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull: false
        },
        last_name: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull: false
        },
        password: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull: false
        },
        created_by: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            allowNull: false
        },
        created_on: {
            type: DataTypes.DATE,
            allowNull: false
        },
        updated_by: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER
        },
        updated_on: {
            type: DataTypes.DATE
        }
    },
    {
        tableName: 'user_master',
        timestamps: false
    }
);
```

This is my Role Model (Role.ts)

```
interface RoleAttributes {
    id: number;
    rolename: string;
    description: string;
    created_by: number;
    created_on: string;
    updated_by: number;
    updated_on: string;
}

type RoleCreationAttributes = Optional<
    RoleAttributes,
    'id' | 'updated_by' | 'updated_on' | 'description'
>;

const Role: ModelDefined<RoleAttributes, RoleCreationAttributes> = sequelize.define(
    'role',
    {
        id: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            autoIncrement: true,
            primaryKey: true
        },
        rolename: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull: false
        },
        description: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull: false
        },
        created_by: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            allowNull: true
        },
        created_on: {
            type: DataTypes.DATE,
            allowNull: true
        },
        updated_by: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            allowNull: true
        },
        updated_on: {
            type: DataTypes.DATE,
            allowNull: true
        }
    },
    {
        tableName: 'role_master',
        timestamps: false
    }
);
```

This is my junction model (RoleModel.ts)

```
interface UserRoleAttributes {
    id: number;
    user_id: number;
    role_id: number;
}

type UserCreationAttributes = Optional<UserRoleAttributes, 'id'>;

const UserRole: ModelDefined<UserRoleAttributes, UserCreationAttributes> = sequelize.define(
    'user_role',
    {
        id: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            autoIncrement: true,
            primaryKey: true
        },
        user_id: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            allowNull: false,
            references: {
                model: User,
                key: 'id'
            }
        },
        role_id: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            allowNull: false,
            references: {
                model: Role,
                key: 'id'
            }
        }
    },
    {
        tableName: 'user_role_master',
        timestamps: false
    }
);

User.belongsToMany(Role, { through: UserRole, foreignKey: 'user_id' });
Role.belongsToMany(User, { through: UserRole, foreignKey: 'role_id' });
```

When I am executing this piece of code to find users with a specific username and joining to access roles
user.roles gives me type error as roles does not exist on user. How can I define the join fields types and where should I define it?

```
const roles = user.roles?.map((role: any) => role.rolename)
```